# Editable Dropdown List in Web2py

Tags: web2py

I need to create a Dropdownlist where in the user can select a value from 
the dropdownlist or type the value in. The Dropdownlist values are stored 
in a database table.

For example: Form looks like this one: 
"Where do you come from?":  Dropdown lists the available cities, if your 
city is not found type in your city.

I tried this code:
`Field('City', requires = IS_IN_DB(db,db.city.id,'%(city)s')`
With this code i can not enter a new city if it is missing in the 
database.

I can only select the available cities in the database.

Model:

```py
 db.define_table('city',Field('name',type='string',length=100,required=True
,notnull=True, ondelete='SET NULL',unique=True),format='%(name)s')
db.define_table('person',Field('name',type='string',length=100,required=Tr
ue,notnull=True, ondelete='SET NULL',unique=True),
Field('city_id','reference city',required=True,notnull=True,label='City'),
format='%(name)s')
db.person.city_id.requires=IS_IN_DB(db,'city.id' ,'%(city)s')
```

Controller:

```py
def person():

     return 

dict(grid=sqlform.grid(db.person,create=True,editable=True,deletable=True)

)

View:

{{extend 'layout.html'}}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">

     {{pass}}

    {{=grid}}

  </div>

</div>
```